# How do you keep a reference to a UICollectionViewCell after launching an asynchronous request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that consists of subclassed UICollectionViewCells.

These cells have buttons on them that make asynchronous requests to an API.  In one case, I have a "heart" button.  Tapping this disables the button and makes an API call asynchronously and passes in a block to use as a callback.  When the call comes back successful, the button gets updated to a different state.

The problem is, the reference to the cell seems to get lost or changed when the code from the block is called. So, bad things happen, like when the cell scrolls off the screen, the state of the button never gets updated and the button stays disabled whenever that cell is re-used.

What is the best practice here?

```
- (void)didTapHeart:(id)sender event:(id)event {
NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.collectionView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];

__block MyObject *object = [myObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
__block CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[sender superview];

cell.btnHeart.enabled = NO;

[[ApiSingleton defaultApi] like:object success:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.btnHeart.enabled = YES;
        object.isLiked = YES;
        object.likeCount++;
        [cell setLiked:YES];
    });

} failure:^(NSDictionary *error) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cell setLiked:NO];
        cell.btnHeart.enabled = YES;
        object.isLiked = NO;
    });
}];
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't keep a reference to the cell - keep a reference to the index path and ask the collection view for the cell at the index path you're concerned about For example:

```
[[ApiSingleton defaultApi] like:object success:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CollectionViewCell *blockCell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        blockCell.btnHeart.enabled = YES;
        object.isLiked = YES;
        object.likeCount++;
        [blockCell setLiked:YES];
    });

} failure:^(NSDictionary *error) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CollectionViewCell *blockCell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [blockCell setLiked:NO];
        blockCell.btnHeart.enabled = YES;
        object.isLiked = NO;
    });
}];
```

Since in this case `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` returns the cell that represents `object`, or `nil` if such cell doesn't exist on screen at that time, you update not just `object` but are guaranteed to update the cell that represents it at the time the callback occurs, so that you don't interfere with other cells. The root of the problem that you are seeing is that cells are re-used by the collection view, so at any given time a cell can represent the data at an entirely different index path.

Completely unrelated, but you don't need to make `object` a `__block` variable, as you never change the value of the variable itself. Same with `cell`, although after this change you won't be using it in the block anyway.

Comment: Perhaps add that `cellForItemAtIndexPath` returns `nil` if the cell is not visible anymore when the completion block is called.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, I edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense. I was worried that calling cellForItemAtIndexPath would run a lot of unnecessary code just to get a reference to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

1> Keep the reference of indexPath.

```
1> Declare the index path variable

   var referenceIndex: IndexPath?

2> set the indexPath in cellForItemAt


     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      referenceIndex = indexPath
}
```

2> And then get the cell like below.

```
if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: referenceIndex) as? CollectionViewCell {
      // Do the expected functionality   
}
```